# getIntent return null - Android

Tags: java, android

I have a project that contains three activities(MainActivity, PlayerActivity and ListActivity). I want to send intent from `MainActivity` to `PlayerActivity` and select a name in `PlayerActivity` and pass it again to`MainActivity.`

I wrote another intent to send some data to `ListActivity` from`Mainactivity`.

`MainActivity` to `ListActivity` works perfect, also `MainActivity`to `PlayerActivity.` but when `PlayerActivity`send Intent to `MainActivity`, I get a null intent.

Here is my code:

Send From ListActivity:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            int buttonId = bundle.getInt("buttonID");
            String name = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            Intent sendIntentToMainActivity = new Intent(PlayersActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();

            bundle1.putString("name", name);
            bundle1.putInt("buttonId", buttonId);

            startActivity(sendIntentToMainActivity);

        }
    });
```

Get in MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        setIntent(intent);
        Log.d("xxx", "Intent is null");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    int id = bundle.getInt("buttonID");
    String name = bundle.getString("name");

    if (id == mButton_first_group_frist_name.getId()) {
        mButton_first_group_frist_name.setText(name);
    } else if (id == mButton_first_group_second_name.getId()) {
        mButton_first_group_second_name.setText(name);
    } else if (id == mButton_second_group_frist_name.getId()) {
        mButton_second_group_frist_name.setText(name);
    } else if (id == mButton_second_group_second_name.getId()) {
        mButton_second_group_second_name.setText(name);
    }
}
```

Please help and give advice

Comment: It doesn't look like you're sending the bundle with the intent.

Comment: have you tried `startActvityForResult` ?

Comment: can you post stacktrace?

Comment: If you find yourself with a List with Model (Player, in your case) page, that should generally be two Fragments, in one Activity. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the bundle to the created intent, and when back to onResume, get the bundle from the intent. You can do that this way:

```java
Intent sendIntentToMainActivity = new Intent(PlayersActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();

            bundle1.putString("name", name);
            bundle1.putInt("buttonId", buttonId);


            sendIntentToMainActivity.putExtra("bundle",bundle1);
            startActivity(sendIntentToMainActivity);
```

And then inside `onResume` :

```html
Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle");
```

Comment: I forgot to send bundle with intent. Thanks guys.